# Create a new interdependent df column using itertuples()

Tags: python, pandas

I am very aware of the strong priority and preference of using scalar operation in the world of pandas dataframe. However I have so far exhausted all the options of an exercise where I need to create a new df column which depends on the previous row's value of another column and the value of such another column would also depends on the previous row's value of the new column and thus these two columns are inter-dependent (not the case of circular-referencing because each of these two columns will depend on the previous values of each another).

A kind of for-loop case (event driven type) is most relevant and I learn of the itertuples() function to start:

`for row in df.itertuples()`

However, I want to know what is the best way to create a new df based on such function? Should I first create a new/blank df column and then do some sort of append function?

Comment: Add some sample data, expected output as text and not as image.

Comment: Can you add a sample input dataframe along with your expected output? you can use df.head(10).to_dict() ??